# Prove that $d$ is an eigenvalue of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, not neccesarily finite dimensional. Let be $T$ a linear operator on $V$. Suppose that there exists a polynomial $0 \neq f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(T)=0$ and let's consider $m(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $T$ over $F$ and $d \in F$ one root of $m(x)$. Prove that $d$ is a eigenvalue of $T$.

I understand that I've to prove that $d$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, i.e., $T \alpha = d \alpha$ for some vector $\alpha \in V$. Also I know that $m(T)=0=f(T)$, but I still don't know how can I use these facts to prove it. I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $m(x)=(x-d)\cdot q(x)$ for some $q(x)\in F[x]$.  Since, $\text{deg}(q)<\text{deg}(m)$, $q$ can not be minimal polynomial of $T$. So, we have a vector $\beta$ such that $q(T)\beta\not=0$. Let $\alpha=q(T)\beta$. Now, $$0=m(T)\beta=(T-dI)\ q(T)\beta=(T-dI)\alpha.$$ Since, $\alpha\not=0$ we are done.